# ¿Cómo emplear el ROWNUM?

Tags: oracle

¿Cómo usar `ROWNUM` en una consulta de 2 tablas para que **me traiga solo el primer registro de 1 curso en caso de tener 2 o mas areas**?.

Es decir, *(ver tabla `Curso`)* que si el `C1` tiene 3 **areas** diferentes que solo me arroje 1 registro *(el que sea)* y que si tiene el `C2` también arroje 1 registro.

¿O hay alguna otra cláusula que pueda emplear?

Tabla: **Curso**:

```
CURSO----NOMBRE DEL CURSO---AREA  
C1---------- ejemplo1---------------------"herramientas"  
C1-----------ejemplo1---------------------"aplicaciones"  
C1-----------ejemplo1---------------------"metodologias"  
C2-----------ejemplo2---------------------"aplicaciones"  
C2-----------ejemplo2---------------------"metodologias"   
C3-----------ejemplo3---------------------"aplicaciones"
```

Tabla **Empleado**:

```
No.Empleado-------NOMBRE-----CURSO  
999--------------------ANA ------------C1  
999--------------------ANA ------------C2  
999--------------------ANA ------------C2
```

Estoy haciendo el `join` y requiero me aparezca algo como lo siguiente:

```
NoEmpleado----NOMBRE----CURSO----AREA  
999----------------ANA--------------C1----------"herramientas"  
999----------------ANA--------------C2----------"Aplicaciones"  
999----------------ANA--------------C3----------"Aplicaciones"
```

Y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Creo que la clausula que buscas es DISTINCT

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer uso de la función analítica `FIRST_VALUE` junto con la claúsula `DISTINCT` para obtener el resultado que quieres.

```
WITH CURSO AS (
         SELECT 'C1' CURSO, 'ejemplo1' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'herramientas' AREA, 1 ORDEN FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C1' CURSO, 'ejemplo1' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'aplicaciones' AREA, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C1' CURSO, 'ejemplo1' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'metodologias' AREA, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C2' CURSO, 'ejemplo2' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'aplicaciones' AREA, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C2' CURSO, 'ejemplo2' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'metodologias' AREA, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'C3' CURSO, 'ejemplo3' NOMBRE_CURSO, 'aplicaciones' AREA, 1 FROM DUAL ), 
     EMPLEADO AS (
         SELECT '999' NUMERO_EMPLEADO, 'ANA' NOMBRE, 'C1' CURSO FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '999' NUMERO_EMPLEADO, 'ANA' NOMBRE, 'C2' CURSO FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT '999' NUMERO_EMPLEADO, 'ANA' NOMBRE, 'C3' CURSO FROM DUAL )
SELECT DISTINCT E.NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
       E.NOMBRE,
       C.CURSO,
       FIRST_VALUE(C.AREA) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CURSO ORDER BY C.ORDEN RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CURSO
FROM CURSO C
JOIN EMPLEADO E ON C.CURSO = E.CURSO
```

Céntrate en el último `SELECT` que es el que tu tendrías que usar. El `WITH` es sólo para simular las tablas de tu ejemplo.

Ten presente que hice una modificación en tu tabla de EMPLEADO, ya que creo que tienes un error allí, pues de la forma como está planteado tu ejemplo, nunca obtendrían en el `JOIN` un registro con el curso 3 (C3). Básicamente, cambie el último registro de tu tabla empleado de C2 a C3.

Finalmente, como no indicaste que órden debe usarse para traer el primer registro, añadí una columna ORDEN en la tabla CURSO. Si lo prefieres podrías usar órden alfabetico modificando el query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.NUMERO_EMPLEADO,
       E.NOMBRE,
       C.CURSO,
       FIRST_VALUE(C.AREA) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CURSO ORDER BY C.AREA RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS CURSO
FROM CURSO C
JOIN EMPLEADO E ON C.CURSO = E.CURSO
```

Saludos